# When to use PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth vs .Viewport.Width

Tags: xna-4.0

Had to shorten the calls to make the question more readable but...
When is correct or incorrect to use on or the other ?

I guess in most cases is the same as you just have the one Viewport but if going split screen I guess you ll have more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want the **viewport** size, as this is the region within which rendering actually takes place.

If you ever add anything like split-screen or picture-in-picture rendering, then you *must* use the viewport. So you may as well use it to begin with.

You should use the backbuffer size only when that is what you actually want. For example, you want the backbuffer when taking screenshots, or setting viewport positions.

I've got a [more detailed answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8694/288) to a very similar question over on the game dev site.